# hidden-xs class in btn-group make a line break

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

all btn's - in a line (http://bootply.com/100575)

when I add hidden-xs into btn-group, it make new line break. (http://bootply.com/100574)

I changed codes but I can not find how to make btn's in a line with hidden-xs.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="./board.php?bo_table=qna&amp;page=1"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>List</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="./write.php?bo_table=qna"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Write</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group hidden-xs"> <!-- here... -->
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:select_delete();">Delete</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:select_copy('copy');">Copy</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:select_copy('move');">Move</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default styling of `.hidden-xs` is:

```
.hidden-xs {
    display: block!important;
}
```

Changing it to `display:inline-block` will solve this.

```
.hidden-xs {
    display: inline-block!important;
}
```

In this instance, usage of `!important` would be necessary since you are having to overwrite the initial declaration which uses `!important`. Alternately just change the bootstrap CSS to `inline-block` and avoid having to overwrite it.

Comment: thanks. It works. great! I just change style. <div class="btn-group hidden-sm hidden-xs" style='display:inline-block!important;'>

Comment: @OpenCode Glad it worked. Bootstrap really makes it difficult to overwrite things. I don't know why they use `!important` so much.

Comment: Oops... with style='' hidden-xs does not work. needs another work-around.

Comment: (http://bootply.com/100580) <span style='display:inline-block!important;'> ... </span> works well. but it make alignment issues. IE 10, chrome btn are not in a line. but, bootply.com shows correct alignment.

Comment: This is what it looks like for me in IE10 http://i.stack.imgur.com/mmq4I.png .. if alignment is the issue, add `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: add a <style>..</style> works well. It will make no issues with bootstrap?

Comment: It shouldn't - no. That is ideally how you should style them. Do you have any examples of it not working?

Comment: thanks. <span style='display:inline-block!important;vertical-align:bottom;'> works well. changed to inline-block, vertical-alignment changes. bootstrap is difficult.

Comment: (http://opencode.co.kr/bbs/board.php?bo_table=qna) btns at the bottom of list. works well. as a php programmer, css is very difficult.

Comment: @OpenCode Glad it worked.. I'm trying to get into PHP myself.